# Is there a way to override UITextView UIKeyInput so can enter text from superview?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitextview

I have a view `TextViewHolder` that has a `UITextView` as a subview. I'd like for `TextViewHolder` to implement `UIKeyInput` and it's three accompanying methods `insertText`, `hasText`, and `deleteBackwards` so that I can insert the text in my `UITextView` from `TextViewHolder` (for messy design purposes) and I'd also like to maintain the functionality of an editable `UITextView` (ala positioning of the cursor, copy paste, ability to add different languages). Is it possible to accomplish this without subclassing the UITextView?

Comment: Could you motivate this a bit more? I mean, UITextView _does_ conform to UITextInput and hence UIKeyInput, what's the problem that needs solving here?

Comment: @matt - trying to fit it into a current design I have that uses a custom textview via CoreText to enter text. I'm wanting to replace that view with a UITextView. In looking into this though, I don't think there is a way to do it without subclassing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible to do unfortunately, need to subclass UITextView and override `insertText` and `deleteBackward`.

Comment: Actually that doesn't work because of iOS bugs: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7519